# How to change php urls on my website?

Tags: php, url

Is it possible to somehow change my website links from:

```
domain.com/category.php?tag=test
domain.com/section.php?tag=test
domain.com/news.php?tag=test
```

into this:

```
domain.com/category-test
domain.com/section-test
domain.com/news-test
```

Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @JacobGoulden that is not going to work. amadeo: it would make more sense to change the urls to _domain.com/category/test_

Comment: use .htaccess for rewrite

Comment: @putvande why would it make more sense to use `/` instead of `-` ?

Comment: @Alexender I just rolled back the edit. Your edit would imply that it has to be done using htaccess - However, this is never mentioned in the question and is not necessary. There are also other valid techniques to do this, while htaccess is certainly the most commonly used.

Comment: Tell me techniques you know better than htaccess.

Comment: @Alexender, you could do it with PHP if you had to.

Comment: @Dorvalla the link you posted is for Apache only. How you know OP doesn't use nginx or a different webserver?

Comment: @amadeo please add your webserver software as a tag so we know what kind of rewrite configuration you need

Comment: @BenM. How can you do this using php ?? Plz explain with example.

Comment: Too lengthy to do so in the comments.

Comment: What I ask is "techniques better than htaccess" ?? Not "techniques ohter than htaccess" ??

Comment: @DanFromGermany I simply point him in the right direction if it comes to PHP. I asumed he runs Apache on his webserver (as it is the most common with 60 percent of the world, and if its used in educational lessons, schools supply apache (or at least my old school did). If he uses something else, than I gladly hear from him and will point him in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. You'll need to create a `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category-([^/]+)/?$ category.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^section-([^/]+)/?$ section.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^news-([^/]+)/?$ news.php?tag=$1
```

Now, accessing `domain.com/category-test/` will take you to `category.php?tag=test`.

If you'd prefer to have slashes instead of dashes, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^section/([^/]+)/?$ section.php?tag=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news.php?tag=$1
```

Comment: How you know OP is using Apache?

Comment: I don't, but until the OP indicates otherwise, it's pretty safe to assume.

Comment: Thanks I got it working! How should the code be if I want a slash instead of a hypen, so it becomes "domain.com/category/test"?

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. With the slashes then the CSS disappears. Should I change the location of my stylesheet.css file?

Comment: Just link to it from the root (i.e. `/css/stylesheet.css`).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^category-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ category.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^section-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ section.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ news.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]
```

In "category.php" file get the tag $_GET['tag'];